# What is the app for OS X that allows you to have a terminal everywhere by pressing a shortcut?

Tags: macos, terminal

The other day I've seen somebody use a MacBook. He had a pretty cool app that allowed him to have a terminal fly down from the top of his screen when pressing a key combo.

Do you know what that app is called? I forgot to write down the name.

He told me there was something similar for Ubuntu, but this was for the Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Visor](https://visor.binaryage.com/)

> a system-wide terminal on a hot-key

It will basically show Terminal.app with a system-wide hot-key from wherever you are.

[image]

---

### [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/)

iTerm2 can also do that if you need a Terminal with a system-wide shortcut. <s>It won't "fly down" though</s> Apparently, it does fly down! iTerm2 has a bit more features than the default Terminal.app, so it's worth taking a look at it.

[image]

Comment: +1, Visor is great. There's another SIMBL-Plugin which works well with Visor, imho a must have: [https://github.com/dabeeeenster/TerminalTabSwitching](https://github.com/dabeeeenster/TerminalTabSwitching) - This allows you to switch tabs in terminal.app with CMD+1/2/3 etc.

Comment: @trurl That's the number 1 feature I was missing from `Terminal.app`, thanks for adding this.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your answer! iTerm actually *does* fly down, when you check the "HotKey toggles a dedicated window with profile".

Answer (score 2):

## DTerm

I use DTerm: http://decimus.net/dterm

The source code is available here: https://github.com/bdrister/dterm

Comment: Please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software.  Thanks.